# Why is it not possible to inherit tests methods from other assemblies

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

WHy is it not possible to inheritance tests from other assemblies to run:

```
namespace TestProject.Base
{
    [TestClass]   
    public abstract class TestBaseClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void BaseTest()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Test Runner

```
namespace TestProject.UnitTest
{   
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest : TestBaseClass
    {
    }
}
```

It is ONLY possible to do run the test when the classes are in the SAME assembly WTF!

Is it possible to have test inheritance like above with NUnit and be runnable?

Comment: What are you seeing that is leading you to this conclusion? An error? No intellisense on the base members?

Comment: Tests dont run!  Tests will only run if i declare both classes in the same assembly.

Comment: "Tests dont run!" Is not an answer to his question.

Comment: Ok. The test methods are not discovered by the editor and therefore do not run.  THe methods can be discovered once i put BOTH classes in the same assembly

Comment: So you are building the class "UnitTest" into a separate DLL and referencing the DLL that contains "UnitTest"? Is the DLL that contains "BaseTest" in the same directory as the "UnitTest" DLL?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems this is a limitation of the MSUnit framework. In the MSDN documentation it states clearly that tests can inherit methods from another test class in the same assembly (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517.aspx).

Probably the cause for this is the way MSUnit discovers tests and so far it seems there is no workaround (other than having a copy of the test files in the project).